# consulta SQL para exibir o total de cada mês

Tags: mysql, sql, query

sempre que preciso tirar alguma duvida sobre programação recorro a esse site, mas dessa vez é uma coisa tão simples que não achei a resposta e nem consegui fazer. Tenho uma consulta que retorna os pedidos de venda de vários clientes, mas preciso que ao final de cada mês nessa tabela tenha a soma de todos os pedidos do mês conforme imagem. É uma consulta normal de uma tabela de vendas.

SELECT * FROM `tb_refeicoes` order by data_refeicao

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbTMj.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/208X7.png)

GRATO PELO AJUDA

Comment: Não poste link de imagens, poste como texto , para uma exibição como a pedida pesquise por "mysql window function running total" ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664436/cumulative-sum-over-a-set-of-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score -2):

Se você quiser gerar uma coluna com os totais de vendas agrupados mensalmente, tente este código:

```
SELECT data, cliente, quantidade, valor, valortotal,
       (SELECT SUM(valortotal)
        FROM tbl_refeicoes
        WHERE MONTH(data) = MONTH(t.data) AND YEAR(data) = YEAR(t.data)) as 'Total Mensal'
FROM tbl_refeicoes t
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((MONTH(data), YEAR(data)), (data, cliente, quantidade, valor, valortotal))
HAVING MONTH(data) IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(data) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN cliente IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    data
```

A cláusula GROUPING SETS permite especificar explicitamente quais conjuntos de colunas devem ser agrupados. o conjunto de colunas (MONTH(data), YEAR(data)) gera uma linha de total para cada mês, e o conjunto de colunas (data, cliente, quantidade, valor, valortotal) gera uma linha de total para cada pedido.

O resultado seria o seguinte:

```
data       cliente    quantidade  valor                 valortotal            Total Mensal
---------- ---------- ----------- --------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
2022-12-25 João       3           12,00                 36,00                 222,00
2022-12-27 Paulo      8           12,00                 96,00                 222,00
2022-12-28 José       6           15,00                 90,00                 222,00
2023-01-01 Carlinhos  22          20,00                 440,00                582,00
2023-01-02 Juquinha   5           14,00                 70,00                 582,00
2023-01-04 Paulinha   8           9,00                  72,00                 582,00
```